# Oracle SQL DB: If equal to Monday then perform a certain statement

Tags: sql, oracle, powerbi

I'm using a SQL statement in Power BI on a Oracle based system to pull some data when the day of the week equals Monday. Ideally, I'm trying to make it so it works in any location. I'm trying to convert "C_endtime" to a day of the week and compare it to the sysdate. Basically if its Monday then I want all the data from that table back to Friday, every other day would just be the previous day's data.

In other words what I'm ultimately shooting for is:

```
...
where
if 
   sysdate = 1 (Monday) 
then 
   pull data back 3 days (sysdate -3) 
else 
   one day (sysdate -1)
```

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT 
   Example Fields                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
FROM 
   Example Table
WHERE

TO_CHAR(c_endtime, 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')  >
   CASE TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') 
      WHEN '1' then sysdate - 3
   ELSE
      sysdate - 1
   END 

AND 
   c_workcentrename = ####
```

I get the error: "ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format."

Comment: You are comparing a string to a date.  That doesn't make sense.  I can't follow your logic, because I don't know which date should be a Monday -- `sysdate` or `c_endtime`.

Comment: I want to pull everything back 3 days if sysdate is Monday... "WHERE c_endtime > sysdate -3 otherwise,  "WHERE c_endtime > sysdate -1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that on Monday you want everything since the beginning of Friday and on other days since the beginning of the previous day, then you can use logic like this:

```
select . . .
from . . .
where ( (trunc(sysdate) = trunc(sysdate, 'IW') and c_endtime >= trunc(sysdate - 3)) or
        (trunc(sysdate <> trunc(sysdate, 'IW') and c_endtime > trunc(sysdate - 1))
      ) and
      c_workcentrename = ###;
```

ISO weeks start on Monday and that is not changing anytime soon or in any environment.

You can simplify the above to:

```
where ( (trunc(sysdate) = trunc(sysdate, 'IW') and c_endtime >= trunc(sysdate - 3)) or
        (c_endtime >= trunc(sysdate - 1))
      ) and
      c_workcentrename = ###;
```

Comment: It seems both sets of codes you wrote didn't produce errors but they didn't filter the table at all unfortunately.

Comment: @C.Mayers . . . That doesn't make sense.  Perhaps you had an error when you added additional conditions.

Comment: I'm not really sure what is happening. It is pulling 2 years less of data now but it's still not pulling only the weekend and friday in this case. Any other suggestions maybe?

Comment: I think I see it now. I changed your "c_endtime < " to "c_endtime >" and it seems to work right now. Thank you!

Comment: @C.Mayers . . . The inequalities were in the wrong direction.  It was getting data from *before* the date in question rather than since.

Answer (score 2):

The result of `TO_CHAR(c_endtime, 'D')` depends on the current user session NLS-Setting, i.e. result is not predictable.

Better use condition like this:

```
IF TO_CHAR(c_endtime, 'fmDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') = 'Monday' THEN
```

or

```
TRUNC(c_endtime) = TRUNC(c_endtime, 'IW') THEN
```

Comment: That is definitely a better way to structure it; I'm still having issues getting the desired result. Here is my current attempt: CASE WHEN
      TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'fmDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') = 'Monday' 
   THEN
      c_endtime > sysdate - 3
   ELSE
      c_endtime > sysdate - 1
   END